# Did Percy Bysshe Shelley take credit for work done by Mary Shelley?

Tags: history, literature, philosophy

This is going to be a rather unorthodox question by me, as I can't fully legitimize the claim about to be questioned, but today, in conversing with a colleague of mine, the Shelleys popped up in conversion. During this conversation I was told by them that much of Percy Shelley's work (or at least some of) was actually just claimed to be his work but was instead written or mostly influenced by Mary Shelley.

Now even though myself and my colleague are not literary scholars, nor even writers or English professionals, I still view most of the things they say as credible as that is what my experience has been with them when fact checking claims they've made before. However, with this most recent claim, I cannot find much. When digging around the only bit of controversy I've found is regarding the debunked claim that Percy was actually the true author of Frankenstein. Yet that kind of is the opposite of the claim made. Ultimately, I'd like to know if there is any evidence that gives weight to this claim, or if there was perhaps another influential romantic era couple of which this dynamic did exist.

Comment: I think this is a fairly widespread claim. Can you add an example of someone making it online? For example on Twitter?

Comment: I'll try to find someone online claiming it. I tried before, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this claim several times.

Comment: If anyone knows a link of the claim made public, please let me know. I'd like to add more legitimacy to the inquiry.

Comment: There's the [Country Life article](https://www.countrylife.co.uk/out-and-about/theatre-film-music/did-mary-shelley-really-write-frankenstein-156234) which points out that Walter Scott's review includes such a statement: "In his review, Walter Scott suggested that it was by Mary’s husband, Percy.", however I can't find the source material for the original statement. which is only perhaps peripheral to the question, unless Scott says otherwise.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Shelley) claims that Mary edited some of Percy's work. *"She also edited and promoted the works of her husband, the Romantic poet and philosopher Percy Bysshe Shelley."*

Comment: @WeatherVane I guess then the question would be: during the time of Percy's life did he give her due credit for her edits and promotions?

Comment: I was suggesting an online reference to the claim that Mary did some of his work - it's your question. Please find a "notable claim". A discussion with friends isn't "notable".

Comment: To whom does "they" refer in the second paragraph?

Comment: Any reference to "they" would be my colleague